# Is redux flat-data going to cache unneeded data?

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx-store

Imagine I have an AngularX single page app with a UI that consists entirely of embedded widgets, so there no route-changes where I can clear down a store's state due to the entire display refreshing.

Using the normalized data approach I see recommended for redux I can see my store's state becoming increasingly full with data that the user might not use again for the rest of the day. For example, scrolling through many months worth of venues + events would locally store lots of Venue details and lots of Event details which most likely will not be used again.

The calendar widget obviously cannot remove items from the store as it moves to different months because other widgets on the same page might depend upon some of the same data (venue details, upcoming events, etc)

I am concerned that redux effectively encourages developers to hold on to data just in case it is in use elsewhere.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Caching data in Redux is really no different than with any other client-side library.  It's up to you to decide how much data you want to cache, and when you might want to clear it out.

There's a relevant discussion in [Redux issue #1824 - Normalizing state and garbage collection](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1824).

You might also want to browse some of the articles in the [Redux Techniques#Normalization](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/redux-techniques.md#selectors-and-normalization) section of my [React/Redux links list](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links).  In particular, the post [Advanced Redux Entity Normalization](https://medium.com/@dcousineau/advanced-redux-entity-normalization-f5f1fe2aefc5) gives some useful ideas for tracking subsets of normalized data.